# Issue implementing StateNotifierProvider from Riverpod

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I am trying to implement a Cart System using Riverpod to manage the state of the Cart.

This is the part where the user clicks on a product to add it to the cart:

```
   GestureDetector(
                      child: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
                      onTap: () async {
                        print("cart test");
                        //create new cart item
                        Cart cartItem = new Cart(
                          id: product.id,
                          name: product.name,
                          oldPrice: product.oldPrice,
                          price: product.price,
                          imageUrl: product.imageUrl,
                          category: product.category,
                          quantity: 1
                        );
                        var cartInstance = context.read(cartListProvider);
                        if(isExistsInCart(cartInstance.state,cartItem))
                          context.read(cartListProvider).edit(cartItem,1);
                        else
                          {
                            context.read(cartListProvider).add(cartItem);//if already available in cart, just increase quantity
                            var string = json.encode(context.read(cartListProvider).state);
                            await storage.write(key: cartKey, value: string);
                            
                          }




                      },
                    )
```

Here you have the  provider class:

```
import 'package:cart_system_riverpod/models/cart.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

final cartListProvider = StateNotifierProvider((ref){

  return CartList([]); //init empty cart

});
```

I have also added ProviderScope to the top of the Widgets tree.

My issue is that I am getting errors implementing:

```
cartInstance = context.read(cartListProvider)
```

and

```
context.read(cartListProvider).edit(cartItem,1);
```

always at the `read(...)` part

The editor shows the hint `The method 'read' isn't defined for the type 'BuildContext'.`

Comment: What version of riverpod are you using?

Comment: @Josteve, flutter_riverpod: ^1.0.3

Comment: Check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71053917/11452511

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Riverpod 1.0.0 `context.read` was removed in favour of `ref.read`

So replace `context.read` with `ref.read`

Try this:

```
    Consumer(
      builder: (context, ref, _) {
        return GestureDetector(
          child: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
          onTap: () async {
            print("cart test");
            //create new cart item
            Cart cartItem = new Cart(
                id: product.id,
                name: product.name,
                oldPrice: product.oldPrice,
                price: product.price,
                imageUrl: product.imageUrl,
                category: product.category,
                quantity: 1);
            var cartInstance = ref.read(cartListProvider);
            if (isExistsInCart(cartInstance.state, cartItem))
              ref.read(cartListProvider).edit(cartItem, 1);
            else {
              ref.read(cartListProvider).add(
                  cartItem); //if already available in cart, just increase quantity
              var string = json.encode(ref.read(cartListProvider).state);
              await storage.write(key: cartKey, value: string);
            }
          },
        );
      },
    );
```

Check [here](https://riverpod.dev/docs/migration/0.14.0_to_1.0.0#syntax-unification) to read more.